# Toggle or change image with "position: absolute" in Hover with Bootstrap

Tags: html, image, twitter-bootstrap, css, hover

I'm using Bootstrap and trying to use CSS to transition between two `position: absolute` images when hovering. I have tried the solutions with fixed `height:` and `position: absolute` properties, but this causes the rows to overlap in Bootstrap.

Can someone help me?
http://s13.postimg.org/3mf4kxcav/Schermata_2015_07_31_alle_15_53_38.png

```css
#box-servizi {
 background: #ffffff;
 margin: 50px 0px;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
 padding-top: 20px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#box-servizi>div {
 margin-top: 25px;
 height: 100px;
 position: relative;
 padding-right: 50px;
}

#box-servizi>div>a>img{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    /* transitions */
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
       -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .4s ease;
         -o-transition: all .4s ease;
            transition: all .4s ease;
}


#box-servizi>div>a>img.normal{
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* IE stuff */
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 2;
}
#box-servizi>div>a>img.hover{
    filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* IE stuff */
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
/* hover */
#box-servizi>div>a:hover>img.normal{
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
#box-servizi>div>a:hover>img.hover{
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
  <div id="box-servizi" class="section-shadow">

   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" id="promozioni">
    <a href="#" title="Scopri tutte le nostre Promozioni">
     <img class="section-shadow img-responsive normal" src="img/box-servizi/promozioni.jpg" alt="Immagine Promozioni Lodigiani Concessionaria" title="Scopri tutte le nostre Promozioni!" />
     <img class="img-responsive hover" src="img/box-servizi/promozioni-h.jpg" alt="Immagine Mouse Hover Promozioni Lodigiani Concessionaria" title="Scopri tutte le nostre Promozioni!" />
    </a>
   </div><!-- /promozioni -->
  </div><!-- /box-servizi -->
 </div><!-- /container -->
<!-- /BOX SERVIZI -->
```

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer

Add the following to your CSS:

```
#promozioni
{
    padding-top: 56.25%;
}
```

*Calculate the proper value for `padding-top` by dividing the **height** into the **width** of your image; I used a 1280 x 720 image in this example, so 720 / 1280 = .5625; or 56.25%.  This is a 16:9 aspect ratio.*

Remove the following property from your `#box-servizi>div` selector:

```
height: 100px;
```

*(1) Using a fixed value in Bootstrap or any other responsive framework will always cause problems, because the sizes of things will change for different size displays; and (2) You don't need it anymore.*

### Explanation

In the CSS block model, a block containing content which is absolutely positioned (`position: absolute;`) will occupy no space in the document flow; it will be 0px wide, and 0px tall for all intents and purposes.  Therefore, you must tell the browser to occupy the area where your image goes with blank space to make everything else flow correctly.  There are two ways to do this:  With the `height:` property (bad idea, especially in a responsive design), or by using `padding-top:` property (the right way in this case).

### Some Coding Tips for Bootstrap

1. `class="container"` divs should be followed by a `class="row"` div, so in your code, change the `#box-servizi` div to read:

   `<div class="row section-shadow" id="box-servizi">`
2. When specifying columns in your Bootstrap grid, you should start with your smallest grid elements and then go up from there:

`<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"></div>`

Which can further be optimized as follows:

`<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4"></div>`

From this example, you can see that once you set a column width (`col-sm-4`), larger column sizes will still be 4 grids wide, until you select a different grid width.  So if sizes -sm- and higher are all 4 grids wide, just use `col-sm-4` and stop there; the rest (`col-md`, `col-lg`) will all be 4 wide also.

Comment: It doesn't work for me.
I have add '#box-servizi>div {
 position: relative;
 padding-right: 50px;
 padding-top: 4%;
 padding-bottom: 4%;
}' but the result is this: http://s29.postimg.org/h4pk3usbr/code.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem with this solution:

```css
/* Servizi
   =================================== */

#box-servizi {
 background: transparent url("../img/box-servizi/servizi.jpg") no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px black;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover #box-servizi {
 background-image: url("../img/box-servizi/servizi-hover.jpg");
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px white;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover #box-servizi h3 {
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   -moz-opacity: 0;
   -khtml-opacity: 0;
   opacity: 0;
}

/* Test Drive
   =================================== */

#box-testdrive {
 background: transparent url("../img/box-servizi/testdrive.jpg") no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px black;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

a:hover #box-testdrive {
 background-image: url("../img/box-servizi/testdrive-hover.jpg");
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px white;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover #box-testdrive h3 {
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   -moz-opacity: 0;
   -khtml-opacity: 0;
   opacity: 0;
}

/* Contatti
   =================================== */

#box-contatti {
 background: transparent url("../img/box-servizi/contatti.jpg") no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px black;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

a:hover #box-contatti {
 background-image: url("../img/box-servizi/contatti-hover.jpg");
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px white;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover #box-contatti h3 {
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   -moz-opacity: 0;
   -khtml-opacity: 0;
   opacity: 0;
}

/* Tagliando
   =================================== */

#box-tagliando {
 background: transparent url("../img/box-servizi/tagliando.jpg") no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px black;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

a:hover #box-tagliando {
 background-image: url("../img/box-servizi/tagliando-hover.jpg");
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px white;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover #box-tagliando h3 {
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   -moz-opacity: 0;
   -khtml-opacity: 0;
   opacity: 0;
}

/* Officina
   =================================== */

#box-officina {
 background: transparent url("../img/box-servizi/officina.jpg") no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px black;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

a:hover #box-officina {
 background-image: url("../img/box-servizi/officina-hover.jpg");
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px white;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover #box-officina h3 {
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   -moz-opacity: 0;
   -khtml-opacity: 0;
   opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- !BOX SERVIZI -->
 <div class="row" id="servizi-bottom">
  <div class="container">

   <a href="#" title="Scopri tutte le nostre Promozioni">
    <div class="servizi-button col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4" id="box-promozioni">
     <h3>promozioni</h3>
    </div>
   </a><!-- /box-promozioni -->

   <a href="#" title="Tutto ciò che offriamo">
    <div class="servizi-button col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4" id="box-servizi">
     <h3>servizi</h3>
    </div>
   </a><!-- /box-servizi -->

   <a href="#" title="Tutto sui nostri Test Drive">
    <div class="servizi-button col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4" id="box-testdrive">
     <h3>test drive</h3>
    </div>
   </a><!-- /box-testdrive -->


   <a href="#" title="Scopri come Contattarci!">
    <div class="servizi-button col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4" id="box-contatti">
     <h3>contatti</h3>
    </div>
   </a><!-- /box-contatti -->

   <a href="#" title="Tagliando">
    <div class="servizi-button col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4" id="box-tagliando">
     <h3>tagliando</h3>
    </div>
   </a><!-- /box-tagliando -->

   <a href="#" title="Le nostre Officine">
    <div class="servizi-button col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4" id="box-officina">
     <h3>officina</h3>
    </div>
   </a><!-- /box-officina -->



  </div><!-- /container -->
 </div><!-- /row -->
<!-- /BOX SERVIZI -->
```

What do you think about?